# Changing iframe attributes with JQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I need iframe size stretch to his container  but there are width and height defined attributes for.
So I would to change this by javascript.
This my starting point:

```
   <div class="emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-vimeo">
<div id="media-vimeo-1" class="media-vimeo">
        <iframe src="http://" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and my JS code:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function()
    {
$("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").setAttribute('height: 100%');
 $("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").setAttribute('width: "100%"');
}
```

but nothing change.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly jQuery has no `setAttribute()` method; it's `attr()`. However, as you're setting the height and width of the `iframe` you can just call `height()` and `width()` separately.

Also note that to set 100% height on an element all parent elements must have a `height` applied to them, which I've done in the example below using CSS:

```js
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  $("#media-vimeo-1 iframe").height('100%').width('100%');
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.emvideo,
#media-vimeo-1 {
  height: 100%
}

iframe { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-vimeo">
  <div id="media-vimeo-1" class="media-vimeo">
    <iframe src="http://" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, I can mix it with vh and vw.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use jQuery for this? Change its height and width using CSS only..

```
body {
    margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
}
iframe {
    display: block;       
    background: #000;
    border: none;         
    height: 100vh;        
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this tip, I didn't know these notations vh and vw .